# The phrasal verb "lay down"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I know that it is very common to place the object after the phrasal verb 'lay down' as follows:

The soldiers laid down their arms.

But can we place the object between the verb and the particle in the above-mentioned construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can say *They laid their arms down*.

The rule of thumb is that a 'light' object—typically no more than two words—follows the verb directly; a pronominal object always takes this position. If the object is 'heavier' than that it usually follows the preposition (particle), to make the construction easier to parse; but this is not a rule, merely a courtesy to your reader.

> John laid it down.
>
> John laid his laptop down *or*
>   John laid down his laptop.
>
> John laid down the laptop he was carrying.
>   John laid the laptop he was carrying down *is grammatically acceptable but awkward.*

Answer (score 2):

**To lay down one's arms is a kind of image or metaphor to mean: stop engaging in war**.

"What will it take for the soldiers to lay down their arms"= Stop fighting in a war or battle.

To **lay arms down** does not mean that. It would mean something like to place weapons or arms on the ground:

The soldiers laid their arms down [on the ground].
The mother laid the baby down [on the bed].

Some  phrasal verbs can change meanings very subtly sometimes.

I would argue that **lay down in the phrase lay down arms** is a **phrasal verb** but **lay arms down [some place] is actually not a real one**. It's a verb with an implied prepositional phrase.